# Why I can't make if a user mention himself with a tree command then send a message to that user? Discord.py

Tags: python, discord.py

I'm trying that if a user mention himself (using tree commands) then send a message to that user, but I can't.

Code:

```
@bot.tree.command(name="bite", description="Bites a user, yum!")
@app_commands.describe(user = "User")
async def bite(interaction: discord.Interaction, user: discord.Member = None):
   if user is None:
       await interaction.response.send_message(f"**{interaction.user.mention}**, you should specify a user!")
       return
   if user is interaction.user: #Here is the problem
       await interaction.response.send_message(f"**{interaction.user.mention}**, you are going to bite yourself? Really? -.-")
       return
   if bot.user == user:
       cembed = discord.Embed(color=0xfacaf5)
       cembed.set_image(url=bgrandomchoice['bite'])
       cembed.add_field(name=f" Ow! That hurts! （　｀ハ ´）", value="")
       await interaction.response.send_message(embed=cembed)
       return
```

What should I put instead of "interaction.user"? If I run the code and I type the command mentioning myself, the program ignores all the "if" and goes to the final lines, which I only want to happen when I mention a user other than mine:

```
    embed = discord.Embed(color=0xfacaf5)
    embed.set_image(url=bgrandomchoice['bite'])
    embed.add_field(name=f" **{interaction.user.name}** has bited **{user.display_name}**! o.o", value="")
    await interaction.response.send_message(embed=embed)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are using `is` instead of `==`.

> `==` determines if the values of two objects are equal, while `is` determines if they are the exact same object.

This means that `user is interaction.user` would return `False` and thus fails the if check.
Therefore, you should be using `==` in this case.

```
if user == interaction.user: ##
    await interaction.response.send_message(f"**{interaction.user.mention}**, you are going to bite yourself? Really? -.-")
    return
#rest of code
```

Reference: [What’s the difference between “is” and “==” in Python?](https://towardsdatascience.com/whats-the-difference-between-is-and-in-python-dc26406c85ad)